# *ngFor add certain div [date] element on certain value [date] change

Tags: angular

I have list of transactions, I'm printing them using `*ngFor`, as of now only time is printed.

```
purchaseRecords = [
  {
    "name": "a13bcd",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-03T04:43:17"
  },
  {
    "name": "e34fgh",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-03T04:53:17"
  },
  {
    "name": "e1234b",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-03T05:43:17"
  },
  {
    "name": "y234nk",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-04T04:43:17"
  }
];



<div *ngFor="let purRecord of purchaseRecords">
   <div>{{purRecord.name}} - {{ purRecord.timestamp | date: 'shortTime' }}</div>
</div>
```

Which prints

```
a13bcd - '9:43 PM'
e34fgh - '9:53 PM'
e1234b - '10:43 PM'
y234nk - '9:43 PM'
```

How to get result like this ?

```
03/05/2019 // How to get date here in the for loop
a13bcd - '9:43 PM'
e34fgh - '9:53 PM'
e1234b - '10:43 PM'
04/05/2019
y234nk- '9:43 PM'
```

When the date changes, how to compare the current `record.timestamp` date with next `record.timestamp` and print date?

Comment: share value of `purchaseRecords`

Comment: To me it seems like you want to print the records grouped into dates. And for thats the best solution will be get them grouped into dates. So in your code create an array of objects that have two properties [{date , transactions :[]}] this will do. Also will recommend have presentation only with *ngFor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by comparing with the previous value and checking index.

```
<div *ngFor="let purRecord of purchaseRecords;let i=index">
  <div *ngIf=" !i || ( purRecord.timestamp | date: 'shortDate') !== (purchaseRecords[i-1].timestamp | date: 'shortDate' ) ">{{ purRecord.timestamp | date: 'shortDate' }}</div>
   <div>{{purRecord.name}} - {{ purRecord.timestamp | date: 'shortTime' }}</div>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kqwyp)

Or alternately group data from the ts file and show data based on that in the template.